# php array remove key and shift values up

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've researched topics similar to this but not exactly what I'm looking to do.
I have a multidimensional array like the following.

```
[code]  =>  BILL
[assets] => Array
    (
        [en] => Array
            (
                [datatype] => My Assets
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [Corporate Equity] => 41
                        [Global Equity] => 24
                        [Fixed Income – Government] => 22
                        [Fixed Income – Corporate] => 8.1
                        [Other] => 3.57
                    )

            )

    )
```

I'd like to remove the first inner array, but preserve the values. Shift them up one level in the array so that it looks like this.

```
[code]   => BILL
[assets] => Array
    (

        [datatype] => My Assets
        [data] => Array
            (
                [Corporate Equity] => 41
                [Global Equity] => 24
                [Fixed Income – Government] => 22
                [Fixed Income – Corporate] => 8.1
                [Other] => 3.57
            )


    )
```

This is just the beginning of the array, there are other instances of the same key `[en]` at the same level.

I've tried unset, array_shift and others but I need to keep the contents of `[en]`, just shift them up one level in the array.

Comment: _there are other instances of the same key [en] at the same level_ How will you deal with the other instances? If you shift them all up, won't you overwrite each previous instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `array_map` which returns an array which contains all elements of the previous array after applying the function.

In this case it will simply take the array at index `en` and add it's contents to the new array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

```
$arr = array('assets' => array(
    'en' => array(
        'datatype' => 'My Assets',
        'data' => array(
            'Corporate Equity' => 41,
            'Global Equity' => 24,
             'Fixed Income – Government' => 22,
             'Fixed Income – Corporate' => 8.1,
             'Other' => 3.57
        )
    )
));

$new_arr = array_map(function ($e) {
    return $e['en'];
}, $arr);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works . . . but I hadn't fully enough described the array.  I've edited my original array as you can see there is a pair [code]=>BILL at the top level and after the array_map filter is applied the result is that [code]=>B.  Why would array_map affect that value?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that assumes the key to always be `en` and the subkeys to always be (only) `datatype` and `data`:

```
$assets['datatype'] = $assets['en']['datatype'];
$assets['data'] = $assets['en']['data'];
unset( $assets['en'] );
```

This code could be problematic for you in the future if that array structure ever changes (it lacks extensibility), but it gets you what you want given the information you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

`array_shift` is the opposite of `array_pop`. Used in stack/queue like structures for removing the fist element http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

What you want to do is flatten the array. But if you want to keep all the other sub-arrays as you mentioned, you might look up `array_merge`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same scenario after using reader to read xml file, the returned array was having inserted 0 key array in each level like the following one:

---

```
'config' =>
           0 => 
               'products' =>
                            0 =>
                                'media' => 
                                 .
                                 .
                                 .
```

so I built a small function to get rid of a specific key and shift up its child's in a two dimensions array, in my case the key was 0. hopping this would help somebody also.

---

```
public function clearMaps(&$maps, $readerMaps, $omittedKey)
{
    if (is_array($readerMaps)) {
        foreach ($readerMaps as $key => $map) {

            if ($key !== $omittedKey) {

                $maps[$key] = [];
                $this->clearMaps($maps[$key], $readerMaps[$key], $omittedKey);
            } else {

                $this->clearMaps($maps, $readerMaps[$key], $omittedKey);
            }
        }
    } else {

        $maps = $readerMaps;
    }
}

// $maps: cleaned array, will start as empty array
// $readerMaps: array needs to be cleaned
// $omittedKey: array key to git rid of.
// first call is clearMaps([], $readerMaps, 0);
```